# Score won't post to Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

I'm going through the `Facebook` game tutorial and am on [part 5 - Publish Open Graph Story.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/open-graph/) This part focuses on posting scores to the users score feed. The problem I'm having is that it executes the code, seemingly without any issues, yet does not post the score on Facebook. Here's the code that should post their score:

```
public void postScore(int score){
    Log.d(TAG, "postScore");
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SESSION == NULL OR IS NOT OPENED");
        return;
    }

    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestPublishPermissions");
        requestPublishPermissions(session);

    }

    Bundle fbParams = new Bundle();
    fbParams.putString("score", "" + score);
    Request postScoreRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
        "me/scores",
        fbParams,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error posting");
                    handleError(error, false);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "successfully posted");
            }
        });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(postScoreRequest);
}// end of postScore() method
```

Where PERMISSIONS is defined as:

```
protected static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

And requestPublishPermissions() is defined as:

```
protected void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS)
                // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
                // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
                .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}//end of requestPublishPermissions() method
```

Any help, suggestions, or advice will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: and what does the log say?

Comment: there is no error log but it does hit the logs I placed in the code so it posts to the logcat: `postScore` and `successfully posted`. Though, when searching all over my Facebook page, I find that it actually has not posted

Comment: Try doing a read (GET) for scores of your app using the scores API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) on the graph explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and see if your scores are being uploaded correctly. Also, is your app categorized as "Games" in the "App Details" settings?

Comment: Okay, so I used the graph explorer as you suggested and a score from my app did show up. However, only one score displayed even though I've done it numerous times, does it only display the highest score?

Comment: Okay so I've noticed that it does display only the highest score. So, it seems my code is working after all. My question now is: does it only show on the ticker, news feed and/or my timeline if I publish the app?

Comment: Facebook generates the news feed stories when you submit the scores. I believe you have to beat any of your friend's score to be eligible to get a story in your timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook controls which goes in as a story and which isn't. When you repeatedly post high scores, it is unlikely that Facebook will post every single story to your timeline. If you want that behavior, I suggest implementing posting directly to the timeline as a custom message instead of relying on scores API to push them for you.